# Can a US citizen skip the line to the US embassy on foreign soil by showing her passport even if she or he has come with a group of people?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, consulates, chennai

So, I am going on a field trip with my classmates to the US consulate in India, Chennai. One of my friends is a US citizen. We want to know if she can or cannot skip the line and go show her passport to the security and be let in first before the rest of our class.

Comment: I would guess that you're all going to be let in at the same time, in whatever order the group arrives at the security checkpoint.  I've certainly never seen separate entry queues at a US consulate or embassy, but I've only been to a few of them.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed as a duplicate - the linked Q&A is about the need to have appointments which is not what this question is asking.

Comment: A "field trip" would normally mean an organized class outing for educational purposes. These things are organized in advance and you make an appointment, you don't need to wait in line. Do you mean this kind of "field trip", or are you just going to the consulate for business?

Answer (score 6):

I’ve been to embassies where there was one (long) line for visa applicants, and US citizens (who would generally either have an appointment, or be there because of an emergency) would be admitted immediately. None of that queueing system would apply to people going there for a field trip, since presumably other scheduling arrangements would have been made for the group.

Comment: I agree - The embassies/consulates I've been to had separate lines for US citizens to gain immediate/quick entry, but I would expect a field-trip group to be processed together as a group